# Trying to formulate an SQL query, JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have 2 tables and would like to get revenue by location as an output using SQL.  I think I need a JOIN (left?) and then GROUP BY on location but for some reason my code isn't working?

Please see below:

[image]

Comment: What ID columns mean ? Looks like they're independent from each other(Films' ID vs. Location's ID)

Comment: No, they are the same - Primary Key

Comment: The data model looks strange. Why are there duplicate locations in the location table? I'd expect two rows, UK and US in that table. Then, shouldn't the revenue be related to a film and a location, i.e. reside in a third table film_location?

Comment: A Primary key vs. Foreign key relation is expected within the definition. But there's no.

Comment: @thorsten, it is a table listing Locations by ID.  For example, Goodfellas location is USA, and so is Annue Hall

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, don't get that?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please clarify via edits, not comments.  This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Ah, okay, you want a 1:1 relation. This is quite rare. (Why isn't there just a location column in the film table, if a film can only belong to one location?) And it isn't well designed either, because you expect the two UK to be the same location actually, but would you consider 'United Kingdom' or 'U.K.' the same, too? If a table name is called location, it should contain unique locations.

Comment: Whats missing is a LocationID in the Films table. And the location table should have like only two records...Example. 1 and 5 are duplicate as is 3 and 6 are duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

That's a join and aggregation:

```
select l.location, sum(f.revenue) revenue
from location l
inner join films f on f.id = l.id
group by l.location
```

Comment: wow, is there an easier way to do it, step by step wise?  I was planning JOIN first then GROUP BY?  That won't work?

Comment: @4agreements: that's what the query does. In general in SQL, you don't do things step by step; you describe the result you want with a query, and the database executes it at once.

Comment: what does the f. mean in revenue?  and f.id?

Comment: f is an alias for films...ie "...join films f..." You really need it when there are field names that are named the same in different tables. The alias helps differentiate which is which.

Comment: ah, thanks - I am looking for the simplest way to do this though, I am getting confused here?

Comment: @4agreements: that is the simplest way to do it. That's a pretty simple SQL query here.